# linking bootstrap carousel to database with php codes

Tags: javascript, php

```
<div class="container slider">
    <div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <?php 
            $slidersor=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM slider");
            $slidersor->execute();

            while($slidercek=$slidersor->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            ?>      
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <a href="blog-page"> <img src="<?php echo $slidercek['slider_resimyol'] ?>" class="d-block w-100" alt="Yeni Blog"> </a>
                    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                        <a href="blog-page" class="a-none">  <h5>First slide label</h5></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
            <?php } ?>
                
        </div>

        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button" data-bs-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">Geri</span>
        </a>
        
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button" data-bs-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">İleri</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Images come from the database but transitions do not occur. It looks like there is no problem in php codes. When I write the php codes into different div, the images from the database appear one under the other. I wonder where the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the active class **only to the first element**.

```
<?php $active = true; ?>
    //your foreach
  <div class="carousel-item <?php echo ($active == true)?"active":"" ?>"> 
    ...
  </div>
    //your foreach end
<?php $active = false; ?>
```

Comment: _Suggestion:_ A shorter way: `<?= $active = isset($active) ? '' : 'active' ?>`. That would handle it all on it's own and you don't need (or rather you shouldn't) define it before the loop and don't need to set it to false in the end.